# Concat "?" when insert new register in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

how are all? I have a problem, it's very strange. I have this script  in SQL:

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Pasajes]') AND 
type in (N'U')) 
BEGIN 
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pasajes]([Observaciones] Varchar(MAX));
END;
INSERT INTO Pasajes(Observaciones) 
  VALUES ('​Que sea hasta puente saavedra, porfa )' );
INSERT INTO Pasajes(Observaciones) 
  VALUES ('​Si puede ser El Pulqui, mejor');
INSERT INTO Pasajes(Observaciones) 
  VALUES ('​A puente Saavedra.');
```

When i run script, i can insert without problem. But if i go to see the rows in table Pasajes, i found this:

[image]

I don't know why concat "?" at the beggining of String. Thank for your help!

Comment: Please tag at least the database engine you’re using

Comment: There is an invisible character at the beginning of your strings. You see it when copying your insert statements into an editor that is capable of showing it. (I am using TextPad and am able to see there is some character: `VALUES ('?Que sea hasta puente saavedra, porfa )' );`.)

Comment: I try, but its the same!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner how can i delete these character? I see now

Comment: Try `update pasajes set observaciones = substring(observaciones, 2, 10000);` Or delete the rows and insert them correctly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i get this value from Sharepoint by c#, i cant write correctly. I need delete in C#, but not all string have this character. How can i take the ascii or something else?

Comment: Then check the first character in C#. With `Regex` or with `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` or something along those lines and then use `String.Substring` to get the string after the invalid character.

Comment: I found the code, thank you! With this i can fix .Replace("\u200B", "");